# Addresables vs Resources vs Asset Bundles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently learning about asset management things, and I figured out that there are three ways to manage assets (Addresables, Resources, Asset Bundles). Resources and Asset Bundles are called "deprecated" here.

**So, does Addresables are going to replace Resources and Asset Bundles?** I am asking because I need to know **which one to learn and utilize in my project**.

Comment: Unity just announced their new [Adressable Asset System](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/07/15/addressable-asset-system/) (15 july 2019). It improve a lot of thing in asset management so it's a good idea to have a look at this but read how the old system works first is a good idea too: [Asset Bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

Comment: Addressable assets *are* asset bundles. Resources is the old way and should not be used any more (though I still find it good for small quick projects where I don't care and it doesn't matter).

Comment: As Draco18s said *Resources* is good for quick prototyping and small "I'll never use it again" projects. Unity recommends to not use it for production though.